# Android 4.4.2 - Background colors not set on spinner

Tags: android, colors, background-color

I have a customized spinner (simple text view) because I wanted to have an easy solution for changing the background colors of selected item:

**spinner_categories.xml**

```
     <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/text1"
         android:layout_width="150sp"
         android:layout_height="40sp"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:gravity="center" />
```

The items are inflated via a custom adapter and the background color changes based on the selected item, where the colors are stored as sharedprefs

**main_acitivity**

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // The spinner items are populated from strings.xml, array elements
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.categories, R.layout.spinner_categories);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        // it sets the background color of the textview based on the selected item
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            sharedpref_colorCategory = getSharedPreferences(COLORS_CATEGORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            parent.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(sharedpref_colorCategory.getInt(spinner.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString(), 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

The text is white on purpose, to create the contrast with the background.

Now, when I install it on my Samsung S5 (Android 5.0 - API 21) or in the emulator, background colors are shown correctly, while one the Huawei Y360 (Android 4.4.2 - API 19) the background color is always white, so I can't see the selected item.
The build.gradle has been configured as follows:

**build.gradle**

```
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Giuseppe

**ANSWER**:
I should use the setBackgroundResource instead and define the colors in the colors.xml file

Comment: After the selection of the item from the Spinner , do u want to change the color of that paricular item or you want to cahnge the color of the whole text inside the Spinner

Comment: I want to change the background color based on the selected spinner item...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the color resource instead of passing the ID, the thing is that `Color.WHITE` just return the id of the resource instead of the color resource, so change this line:

```
((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

for this

```
(TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Comment: It's not about the text color but the background color...I read more about and it seems that I should use the setBackgroundResource instead and define the colors in the colors.xml file :S

Comment: Yes, is the same logic, just add the colors to your colors.xml and follow this approach.

Comment: To set a background color is the same just do:

view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorresid));

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the properties of the TextView in your Adapter. To do this you have to create a custom adapter and handle the TextView properties in the getCustomView method of the adapter. See [this](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2013/06/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html) example.

Comment: the spinner is inflated dinamically based on the items defined in the strings.xml, so in this way i don't have to change anything in the layout...for this reason, the background color is determined at runtime when the item is selected

Comment: any changes that you make to your arrayadapter after it is created will not take effect. therefore, you need a custom adapter